# Nested for loops. Why does inner variable value reset?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, nested

We've been learning for loops and nested for loops.

My question;

Why is it that the value of the variable in an inner for loop resets itself once the increment is over? However in the outer for loop, the variable maintains its value.

For example:

```
public class Factorial {
    public static void main(String[] arguments){
    for(int i = 0; i <10; i++){
        for (int count=6; count < 18; count+=6){
            System.out.println (count);
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

In this case, the program runs 10 times whilst incrementing i and count increments to 18 but then goes back to 6? each time...Could someone explain why this is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Loop counters are local variables, their scope only extends as far as the structure they are created in. As soon as you leave a loop, it's counter no longer exists.

Answer (score 1):

Each time the code executes the line containing :

```
int count=6
```

The count variable goes back to 6.

As you said it, the first loop executes 10 times, so count will be reset the amount of times the first loop executes.

Comment: Is it ?, so it should do the same for `for (int count=6; count < 18; count++){`

Comment: Suresh, when we are in the nested loop looping, we stay in the same round in the main loop...

Answer (score 1):

6 is reinitialized in the statement

```
for (int count=6; count < 18; count+=6){
```

But if you moved the initialization before the loop

```
int count = 6;
for (; count < 18; count+=6){
```

It would do the same thing.

If you moved it further back

```
int count = 6;
for(int i = 0; i <10; i++){
    for (; count < 18; count+=6){
        System.out.println (count);
        }
    } 
}
```

Then the inner loop wouldn't execute iterations i=1..9 because count is already 18.